# traer informacion de la base de datos con angular 2

Tags: angularjs-2.0

Soy nuevo en angular 2,use un poco angular 1x para un proyecto de la universidad.

Mi duda es con angular 2 ¿se puede traer información de la base datos?

Por ejemplo de una base datos en MySQL pero mi pregunta es cómo.
En angular 1 hacía un script en php que hacía una consulta a la base de datos
pero en [angularjs-2.0](/questions/tagged/angularjs-2.0) es lo mismo? ¿Cómo traigo información de la base de datos?

Casi todos los ejemplos que he visto usan `@angular/http` con el método `.get(<la url>)`
pero usan un archivo `.json` en vez de registros de una tabla.

Yo he pensado en poner un archivo `.php` en la carpeta de un componente 
que haga la consulta al server,
pero no estoy del todo seguro por qué en el método `http.get(<la url>)`
en la url no se cómo poner la dirección.
He probado con un `.json` y todo bien pero para traer datos del server tengo dudas.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Si bien podrías conectarte directamente desde Angular2, representa una mala práctica, ya que implica exponer la base de datos al cliente. El método que mencionás, conectando a un servidor intermedio es el preferido.

---

Para poder hacer el *request*, el script PHP tiene que estar hosteado en un servidor web (incluso si es dentro de la misma máquina). De esa forma, `<la url>` será la url en donde esté tu script, ya sea en `http://localhost/xxxx/tu_script.php` o donde esté hosteado.

#### Código

A grandes rasgos, y sólo a modo de ejemplo

**Desde Angular2**

```
import {Http, Response} from 'angular2/http';


class Componente {
  data: Object;

  constructor(private http: Http) {
    http.get('http://localhost/xxxx/tu_script.php')  //usar la url que corresponda
        .map((res: Response) => res.json())
        .subscribe(
            res => this.data = res,
            err => console.error(err),
            () => console.log('Funciona!')
        );
  }
}
```

**En PHP**

```
<?php

    //Conectar a MySQL y obtener los valores deseados.. 
    // En este ejemplo se asume que ya tenemos los datos en un array
    $json['query_de_bd'][] = array(
        'campo1' => 'valor1', 
        'campo2' => 'valor2',
        'etc'    =>  '...'
    );

    //Enviar headers y el JSON como respuesta
    header('Content-Type: application/json');
    header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
    echo json_encode($json);
?>
```

Comment: ya muchas gracias!! MAriano pro tu tiempo lo logre resolver

Answer (score 3):

Para traer datos a *Angular 2* desde una base de datos *MySQL*, te recomiendo utilizar lo siguiente.

- Utiliza los [services](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/tutorial/toh-pt4.html) de *Angular 2* para hacer peticiones a una *API RESTFul*.
- Crea del lado del servidor *API RESTFul*, que reciban y devuelvan datos de tipo *JSON* para una mejor velocidad de transferencia de datos y para que los puedas procesar en la vista de *Angular 2* correctamente.
- Te recomiendo utilizar [Express](http://expressjs.com/es/api.html) con *Node JS*.

Mira un ejemplo de cómo hacer una petición e imprimir los datos en la vista.

[Petición HTTP Angular 2](https://www.uno-de-piera.com/angular2-peticiones-http/)

Answer (score 1):

Si la tecnica es la misma, aunque por supuesto el codigo difiere al tratarse de TypeScript, desde angular 2 tiene el http para poder invocar un servicio que devuelva json

Si analiza la documentacion

[http client](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/server-communication.html#!#http-client)

veras que al crear el servicio se importa

```
import { Http, Response } from '@angular/http';
```

es por medio de este que invocaras el servicio usando `http.get` el cual devolvera un observable (seria el equivalente al promice)

Comment: muchas gracias Leandro, pero sabes tengo otra duda usando http.get (la url) cual seria el path donde se encuentra mi script yo lo tengo asi   dentro de una funcion return **this._http
   .get("app/data/sql.php")** le estoy pasando  la direccion que tiene el script no estoy seguro la verdad