# ¿ Como conectar Angularjs2 con el servidor?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

Estoy intentando hacer una conexión de Angularjs2 con el servidor pero no he podido, voy a colocar el código de mi archivo "app.ccomponent.ts" para dar mayor explicación:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Http } from '@angular/http';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operator/map';
import { Observable }     from 'rxjs/Observable';

@Component({
 selector: 'app-root',
 templateUrl: './app.component.html',
 styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})

export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  title = "Http";
  datos = Object;

  constructor(private http: Http){}

  ngOnInit(): void {

      this.http.get('http://localhost:4200/items.php').map((res: Response) => res.json())
    .subscribe(
        res => this.datos = res,
        err => console.error(err),
        () => console.log('Funciona!')
    );
  }
 }
```

El provider del servicio Http lo inyecto en el modulo principal, por eso no aparece el provider en este archivo.

En el punto donde aparece el operador "map" tengo muchos problemas, si dejo el parámetro tal cual con sus paréntesis  (res: Response) me lanza el siguiente error:

> [ts]
>   Argument of type '(res: Response) => Promise' is not assignable to parameter of type '(value: Response, index: number) => Promise'.
>     Types of parameters 'res' and 'value' are incompatible.
>       Type 'Response' is not assignable to type 'Response'. Two different types with this name exist, but they are unrelated.
>         Property 'body' is missing in type 'Response'.

Si quito los parentesis y lo dejo como res: Response .. entonces lanza el siguiente error:

> [ts] Cannot find name 'res'.
>   any

Si quito el tipo "Response" como tipo de parámetro y le coloco "any" como valor o simplemente le quito el tipo de parámetro pues me deja compilar pero en la corrida me da errores. Estoy corriendo la app con "ng serve", se nota en el parámetro que le paso a la función "get".

Mi archivo items.php es el siguiente:

```
<?php

// Conectar a MySQL y obtener los valores deseados.. 
// En este ejemplo se asume que ya tenemos los datos en un array
$json = array(
    'campo1' => 'Jose', 
    'campo2' => 'Miguel',
    'campo3' => 'Cabrera'
);

//Enviar headers y el JSON como respuesta
header('Content-Type: application/json');
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
echo json_encode($json);
```

?>

Mi código ha cambiado mucho, es decir he intentado distintas maneras de conectarme al servidor y no he podido, específicamente también he seguido los ejemplos de estas dos paginas:

[traer informacion de la base de datos con angular 2](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/17600/traer-informacion-de-la-base-de-datos-con-angular-2)

[Pagina de Alberto Basalo, academia-binaria.com](http://academia-binaria.com/comunicaciones-http-observables-con-angular2/)

Ninguno de los ejemplos me funciona, no se que estoy haciendo mal. No he podido establecer una conexión exitosa entre angulajs2 y el servidor.

Comment: Disculpa. Pero el import de map, no es `import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';`?

Comment: Por cierto, no tienes modelos Javascript o Typescript en los que quieras convertir la respuesta? Por último, qué onda la línea `datos = Object`?

Comment: @Francute Cuando coloco el 'rxjs/add/operator/map' me dice que no lo consigue en la ruta, así como lo tengo si lo ve. Ese `datos = Object` solo lo puse por buscar una alternativa, estoy aprendiendo Angularjs, igual podria colocar `any` y me dara el mismo resultado.

Comment: @Francute realmente lo único que deseo es conectarme al servidor de alguna manera, no estoy haciendo nada especifico, no tengo un modelo por eso mismo. Supuse que con enviar un simple arreglo del servidor al cliente era suficiente.

Comment: Mas que nada decía porque datos = Object es una declaración con asignación, no es una declaración que defina un tipo de variable. En cuanto al resto, no veo muy bien que hay de malo. ¿Cuando entras a localhost:4200/items.php puedes ver un json sin problemas, cierto? ... Ya sé qué puede ser. ¿Tenés implementado CORS del lado servidor para poder acceder desde Angular? Ambos estarían trabajando desde dominios diferentes (A pesar que sea localhost)

Answer (score 0):

Por partes porque son varias cosas. Lo primero de todo. AngularJs 2 no existe. Dices que estás aprendiendo por eso aclararte ese aspecto. Una cosa es Angular JS. Que son las versiones 1.X de Angular y luego está Angular (que es lo que tu estás utilizando) que son las versiones de angular de la 2.0 en adelante.

Dicho esto te sugiero que eches un ojo a algún manual de typescript. Por ejemplo a la hora de declarar las variables lo correcto sería

```
title: string;
title = 'Http';
```

Dicho esto te corrijo algunas cosillas del código a ver si así conseguimos que funcione.

**Los imports**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Response} from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/operator/map';
import { Observable }     from 'rxjs/Observable';
```

Como verás la importació del map se hace con `import 'rxjs/operator/map';` No es necesario poner lo que tenían anteriormente. Además te añado la importación de `Response` .

**Exportación de la clase y constructor**

```
 export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
    datos: any;


      constructor(private http: Http){}
```

Aquí hemos cambiado un par de cosas. Primero el http del principio no es necesario ya que en el constructor ya estás declarando una variable privada llamada `http`. Y la variable datos. Si no sabes que devuelve el servidor pues la incializamos a any directamente y listo.

```
ngOnInit(): void {

      this.http.get('http://localhost:4200/items.php').map((res: Response) => res.json())
    .subscribe(
        res => this.datos = res,
        err => console.error(err),
        () => console.log('Funciona!')
    );
  }
 }
```

En principio con esto ya tendría que funcionar aun que no estoy muy seguro de si el `.subscribe` funcionará correctamente sin estar dentro de un metodo `observable`.

Si te da algún tipo de error, comentalo y lo miramos.